# Convert animated UIImage into NSData

Tags: ios, animation, uiimage, nsdata, archive

I'm using `animatedImageWithImages()` class method of `UIImage` to create an animated image but how can I convert it into an NSData object? I tried using `UIImagePNGRepresenation()` but unfortunately it does not seem to work with animated `UIImage`s. Any idea?